# "Unknown deriving trait ToJson"; What makes a trait derivable?

Tags: json, rust

I'm using the `Json` enum as data type system in my parser, so I use `ToJson` trait to transform data, instead of `Encodable` and `Decodable` which converts data into string directly.

The issue is I cannot use `#[deriving()]` for the `ToJson` trait:

```
#[deriving(ToJson)]
struct Point {
  x: i32,
  y: i32
}
```

The code won't compile because of error:

```
unknown `deriving` trait: `ToJson`
```

So my question is,

1. What's the difference between `ToJson` and `Encodable` as a trait that makes the later derivable?
2. Is it possible to make ToJson derivable and then make conversion from custom struct to the `Json` enum more user-friendly?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237590/rust-json-serialization-overlapping-responsibilities, but that question is not answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question you posed in your title, instead of the two additional questions in your body ([See this Meta post for why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts))

You can use `deriving` because it is a *syntax extension* that has been [registered with the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8f51ad2420776925c12be67a7bf38ac28343fd1f/src/libsyntax/ext/deriving/mod.rs)

This syntax extension has a list of items that build appropriate code at compile time. For example, you can see how [Encodable is defined](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8f51ad2420776925c12be67a7bf38ac28343fd1f/src/libsyntax/ext/deriving/encodable.rs). I do not believe it is possible to add more items to the list supported by `deriving` other than by changing this code and recompiling it.

Comment: In other words, the list of derivable traits (and how they are derived) is hardcoded in the compiler. However, with custom [syntax extensions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-plugin.html) (which are still experimental right now), it's possible to define a custom attribute that lets you derive a trait automatically.